# Retrieving current user location in Android and sending it to Firebase after Location Services have been enabled

Tags: android, firebase, geolocation

I've been planning to create two versions of an app where the 'user' sends their current location to Firebase where it can be retrieved by the 'admin' in the other version and displayed on a map. I'm planning to achieve the first part by putting the location permissions and the sending of the location to Firebase in a single button. Is this possible?

Here's what I have so far:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_location);

    hotlineNumber.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
    hotlineNumber = findViewById(R.id.hotlineNumber);
    hotlineNumber.setText("9-11");

    sendLocation = findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    sendLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
            locationRequest.setFastestInterval(2000);

            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                    .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
            builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

            Task<LocationSettingsResponse> result = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(getApplicationContext())
                    .checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

            result.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task) {

                    try {
                        LocationSettingsResponse response = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                        Toast.makeText(SendLocation.this, "GPS is already turned on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } catch (ApiException e) {

                        switch (e.getStatusCode()) {
                            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:

                                try {
                                    ResolvableApiException resolvableApiException = (ResolvableApiException)e;
                                    resolvableApiException.startResolutionForResult(SendLocation.this,REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException ex) {
                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                break;

                            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                                //Device does not have location
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });



        }
    });


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS) {

        switch (resultCode) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is turned on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is required to be turned on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What's the problem with the code that you shared? So if you run this code in a debugger, and step through it line by line, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: There is no problem with the code I've shared, I wanted to know which 'direction' should I take on how to proceed with putting in the sending of your location to firebase.

Comment: You seem to be reading the location already. Is that working? If so, writing it to Firebase (either [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) or [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)) should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Do you know have any sample codes I can start working with? I tried for tutorials online using Geofire, but there aren't any.

Comment: Writing a location to the database doesn't require GeoFire. And see the links I provided earlier on how to write to the two databases that Firebase has. If you *do* have a need for GeoFire, the documentation ([Realtime Database](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-android), [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries)) are again good places to start.